# Network-policy file to allow traffic from only certain IP adress

Tags: firewall, kubernetes-networkpolicy

How to write network policy files to allow traffic to access the application from only few IP address (eg: 127.18.12.1,  127.19.12.3 ). I have referred the file https://github.com/ahmetb/kubernetes-network-policy-recipes but didn't find satisfactory answer. It would be great if anyone help me to write the network-policy file. I also referred Kubernetes official document for network-policy.

My sample code

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
    name: test-network-policy
    namespace: example
spec:
    podSelector:
      matchLabels:
        app: couchdb
  policyTypes:
  - Egress
  egress:
  - to:
    - ipBlock:
        cidr: 127.18.12.1/16
    ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
```

Answer (score 0):

If you donot want to edit networkpolicy and restrict traffic from ingress for particular domain you can edit ingress with annotation liked :

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: restricted-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/from-to-www-redirect: "True"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "True"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range: "00.0.0.0, 142.12.85.524"
```

for network policy

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: test-policy
  namespace: default
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      app: db
  policyTypes:
  - Ingress
  - Egress
  ingress:
  - from:
    - ipBlock:
        cidr: 172.17.0.0/16
        except:
        - 172.17.1.0/24
    - podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      role: frontend
ports:
- protocol: TCP
  port: 6379
```

egress:
  - to:
    - ipBlock:
        cidr: 10.0.0.0/24
    ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 5978